# NextFocus editText in include layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, focus, android-databinding

I create a simple layout containing my label and my editText. This layout is included several time to create a form.

But with this method the "nextFocus" function doesn't work properly and I can't find a solution. I need to give the id of the next editText but because it's inside a include layout, the id is the same as the current editText.

Is their a way to achieve this by using only xml solution? I particulary think of databinding.

This is my layout's :

**The include layout :**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<data>

    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="viewModels.StringDataTypeViewModel"/>

    <variable
        name="nextFocus"
        type="Integer"/>

</data>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:padding="10dp"

    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"

        tools:text="Nom de famille : "
        android:text="@{viewModel.label}"

        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"/>

    <EditText android:id="@+id/value"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"

        android:textSize="@dimen/patient_detail_edittext_text_size"

        android:inputType="textPersonName"

        android:ellipsize="end"
        tools:text="Dupont"
        android:text="@={viewModel.value}"
        android:textColor="@android:color/widget_edittext_dark"

        android:clickable="@{viewModel.editable}"
        android:cursorVisible="@{viewModel.editable}"
        android:focusable="@{viewModel.editable}"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="@{viewModel.editable}"

        android:background="@{viewModel.editable ?  @android:drawable/edit_text : @drawable/empty_drawable}"

        android:nextFocusForward="@id/value"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**The form layout :**

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="@{viewModel.editable ? View.VISIBLE: View.GONE}">

                <include layout="@layout/string_data_type_layout"
                    app:viewModel="@{viewModel.familyNameViewModel}" />

                <include layout="@layout/string_data_type_layout"
                    app:viewModel="@{viewModel.givenNameViewModel}" />

                <include layout="@layout/string_data_type_layout"
                    app:viewModel="@{viewModel.patientCodeViewModel}" />

                <include layout="@layout/string_data_type_layout"
                    app:viewModel="@{viewModel.addressViewModel}" />


            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately no

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1**: Give unique ids to **all** your **include** elements

```
<include android:id="@+id/edit_text_1"
            ... />
<include android:id="@+id/edit_text_2"
            ... />
```

**Step 2**: Add these attributes to the **root** of your **included** layout xml (LinearLayout in your case)

```
<LinearLayout
        android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        ... />
```

**Step 3**: Use the ids defined in step 1 in all your include elements (as per required navigation)

```
<include android:id="@+id/edit_text_1"
         app:nextFocus="@{@id/edit_text_2}"
         ... />
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to change the id of EditText?

This is work for me:

1.The include Layout:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

...

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ...>
    
    ...

    <EditText android:id="@+id/et_common"
    .../>

</LinearLayout>
```

2.Create an id in ids.xml

```
<item name="next_focus_et" type="id"/>
```

3.Set next focus on another view

```
<Button 
  android:id="@+id/btn"
  android:nextFocusUp="@id/next_focus_et"
.../>
```

4.Change the id of EidtText to "next_focus_et" in the code.

```
private void initComplexNextFocus(){
    mBinding.includeStaticDns2Edit.et_common.setId(R.id.next_focus_et);
}
```